# Does using Expires parameter with put_object() in s3 for uploading deletes the file from s3 after a time period

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-s3, boto3

I am currently using s3 put_object() to upload some files which are required to be deleted after 12 hours. I came across the Expires argument in put_object() in s3 documentation. But using it doesn't delete the file. What can be the issue?

```
 today = datetime.datetime.now()
 expiry_time = today + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
 s3.put_object(
        Bucket='Bucket',
        Key = 'path',
        Body = buffer,
        ContentType = 'image/png',
        ACL = 'public-read',
        Expires = expiry_time

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Radu already said, the expires parameter on the putobject is not for deleting objects.

Generally the way to delete objects from S3 on a schedule you would use [s3 lifecycle events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html), however the smallest amount of time is 1 day, so that wouldn't work in your case.

Most likely you will need to have some custom code running somewhere that cleans up files for you on the schedule you need.

Answer (score 2):

You are not defining an Object Expiration Policy, you are setting the value for when the object is not cacheable any more.

This is related to [HTTP Expires header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) and not S3 Object Expiration Policy.